# Routing Number and Account Number

Tags: banking, bank-account

Why is my routing number showing up as a different bank then the one I bank with? When I enter my account and routing numbers, the bank shows up as Bank Y instead of my normal Bank X.

Comment: Did you mis-type the routing number?  Did Bank Y buy out Bank X?

Comment: Did you call the bank and ask them?

Comment: Can you add a country? Could the two banks be part of a larger banking group?

Comment: Showing up where? When you enter your numbers where?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there is no mistake, many smaller banks contract services like electronic transfers, check processing, debit cards, and even investments to a larger bank. The large bank is called a *correspondent bank* or a *banker's bank*. The name of the larger bank will show up as money is actually going through them.

This is very prevalent in credit unions as well, here the large bank is called a *corporate credit union*.

Comment: In the UK many Building Societies used to (and some still) do something similar. Because they are not part of the main bank clearing system (BACS) they have an account with one of the main "high street" banks and keep their own records of how much of the money belongs to each of their customers. When sending money to one of their customers, the destination sort-code/account number is that of the Building Society's account, and a "reference" field needs to be the Building Society's "customer number" (often called "Roll Number") for that person.